# Issues after migration to Angular2 final - Unexpected token <

Tags: angular

I tried creating a sample project from quickstart in angular 2.0.0 in aspnetcore, The application is compiling but when i execute the application i am getting the following error in the chrome console

```
[![index.html:17 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:49928/app/main.js:6:36)
        at eval (http://localhost:49928/app/main.js:10:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:49928/app/main.js:11:3)
    Evaluating http://localhost:49928/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:49928/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:49928/app/main.js][1]][1]
```

I have checked in the application in the [Github](https://github.com/snkrishnan1/Angular2AspNetCore).

I tried debugging the Network tab in the chrome console and notice that Index.html is rendered multiple times. Please refer the attached snapshot. 
[image]
As per the error in the line: 17 of index.html it tries to load the application

```
System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```

Please find the systemjs.config.js file

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I have updated the changes in the github which is a working solution in Final version, anybody who wants the seed project for angular2 final in aspnetcore can use it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have a look at your code. You should be:

1. Changing templateUrl to template in AppComponent.ts
2. Using gulp to copy all libraries need for your app into your lib
   folder and change npm to lib as:

   'npm': 'lib/'

Hope this help!